# Getting validation error in grails version 3.3.11 but not in grails 2.0.1

Tags: grails

Getting validation error in grails version 3.3.11 but not in grails 2.0.1

Please find sample code below

```
//**Domain classes**

class Booking {
    String bookingtype;
    Patient patient
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class ContactDetails {
    String city
    String state
    String postCode

    static constraints = {
        city blank: false
        postCode blank: false
        state blank: false
    }
}

class Patient {
    String name;
    ContactDetails contactDetails

    static embedded = ['contactDetails']

    static constraints = {
        contactDetails nullable: true
    }
}


//**Controller**
class NewHomeController {

    def index() { }

    def createContactDetails(){
        def patient=new Patient()
        patient.name="Name"
        patient.contactDetails=new ContactDetails()
        patient.save(flush: true,deepValidate:false)
        def booking=new Booking()
        booking.bookingtype="Online"
        booking.patient=patient;
        booking.save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
        render "Done"
    }
}
```

If I run above code in grails 2.0.1 it is running fine but not in grails 3.3.11.
If I persist object as booking.save(flush: true,deepValidate:false) then it is working fine since it will ignore validating child associations.

There is no difference in auto table creation in from grails 2 to grails 3

```
**Grails 3**
--------
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
   id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `contact_details_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_country` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_post_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 
 
 CREATE TABLE `contact_details` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `country` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `post_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 
 
 CREATE TABLE `booking` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `patient_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `bookingtype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK1o2fk91av3dkwlxpexo94lcbg` (`patient_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK1o2fk91av3dkwlxpexo94lcbg` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 
 
 
 **Grails 2**
 ---------
 
 
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `contact_details_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_country` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_post_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contact_details_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 
 CREATE TABLE `contact_details` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `country` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `post_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 
 
 CREATE TABLE `booking` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `bookingtype` va rchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `patient_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FK3DB0859F465DE24` (`patient_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK3DB0859F465DE24` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**The validation exception which I'm getting is**

```
Caused by: grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking' on field 'patient.contactDetails.city': rejected value [null]; codes [domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.error.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.error.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.error,contactDetails.city.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.error.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.error.java.lang.String,contactDetails.city.nullable.error,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.patient.contactDetails.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.city,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.city.nullable,contactDetails.city.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.patient.contactDetails.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.city,contactDetails.city.nullable.java.lang.String,contactDetails.city.nullable,nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.city,nullable.patient.contactDetails.city,nullable.city,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [city,class domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
- Field error in object 'domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking' on field 'patient.contactDetails.state': rejected value [null]; codes [domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.error.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.error.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.error,contactDetails.state.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.error.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.error.java.lang.String,contactDetails.state.nullable.error,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.patient.contactDetails.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.state,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.state.nullable,contactDetails.state.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.patient.contactDetails.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.state,contactDetails.state.nullable.java.lang.String,contactDetails.state.nullable,nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.state,nullable.patient.contactDetails.state,nullable.state,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [state,class domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
- Field error in object 'domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking' on field 'patient.contactDetails.postCode': rejected value [null]; codes [domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.error,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.patient.contactDetails.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.error.java.lang.String,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.error,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.patient.contactDetails.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.postCode,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable.java.lang.String,domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails.postCode.nullable,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.patient.contactDetails.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.postCode,contactDetails.postCode.nullable.java.lang.String,contactDetails.postCode.nullable,nullable.domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.Booking.patient.contactDetails.postCode,nullable.patient.contactDetails.postCode,nullable.postCode,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [postCode,class domain_constraint_verification_3_3_11.ContactDetails]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
```

Didn't find any updates related to validation in latest grails docs.
Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Which validation error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by disabling deep-validate since in newer versions of grails there are some updates to deep-validation.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about "some updates to deep-validation"? Then you answer would actually be very helpful :)

Comment: @SebastianH Please refer this links [https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1150](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1150) and [https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1106](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1106) to get few more updates b/w Grails-2.5.x to Grails 3

Comment: Many thanks for this interesting (though very technical) read. It would be great if the team documented the changed validation behaviour (and its configuration options) between Grails 2.5 and Grails 3 (and thereby Grails 4) in a consistend way ;)